# Можно формулу по которой можно получить значение absoluteX и absoluteY?

Tags: java

У меня есть переменные

```java
public double x, y;
public int absoluteX, absoluteY;
```

например x и y равны 0.5 absoluteX и absoluteY это позиция на экране, максимум 1920 1080 как мне по x, y получить absoluteX, absoluteY в данном случае (x y = 0.5) значит absoluteX = позиция экрана по X координате (1920) а absoluteY = позиция экрана по Y координате (1080)

если x ровняется 1.0 значит absoluteX будет максимальным (1920) с y такая-же ситуация

Comment: Составьте пропорцию.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy какую?

Comment: `x/1 = absX/1920`.

Comment: это немного не то что мне надо или-же я не понимаю как её правильно использовать, не могли бы вы дать пример java кода как это сделать?

Comment: Ну, можно например анализировать расположение курсора как раз получите то, что хотите, если я верно понял, но есть нюанс, что он отработает только тогда когда мышь будет наведена на компонент, то есть идея норм, если у вас есть какой-то графический компонент.

Comment: @ДмитрийАлексеенко я сохраняю эти значения в переменной, после этого я уже отрисовываю это на экране по AbsolutePos

Comment: Прикладывайте ваш код, где некорректно рассчитываются данные

Comment: @ДмитрийАлексеенко "Ну, можно например анализировать расположение курсора" можно код как это реализовать?

Comment: @SDWASAS можно для начала попробовать что-то реализовать самому

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Умножить размеры экрана на х и у, разве нет?

```
absoluteX = 1920 * x  // == 960
absoluteY = 1080 * y  // == 540
```

Comment: уже как давно сам понял как это сделать, но всё же сочту как правильный ответ